# EEG correlates of handedness

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, motor, neuroimaging, eeg, lateralization

Can any one suggest a good article about features of EEG of left-handed people?

I was surprised when find that there are only few old articles about it. I find only one new article by Propper, Ruth E., et al. (2012). Maybe I miss something.

> [Propper, R. E., Pierce, J., Geisler, M. W., Christman, S. D., &
>   Bellorado, N. (2012). Asymmetry in Resting Alpha Activity: Effects of
>   Handedness. Open Journal of Medical Psychology, 1(4), 86-90.](http://www.scirp.org/journal/PaperDownload.aspx?DOI=10.4236/ojmp.2012.14014)

Comment: I haven't read that, but they're likely going to just be correlations that may have little to do with the actual "handedness" difference.  Look into hearing, as a small percentage of left-handed people have their dominant cortices for speech and language shifted to the other side.  This is not a reliable indicator, though, as even most left handed people have the same placement of Broca's area, etc.

Comment: It does not matter. I don't interesting in language or motor areas specifically. Not-right handedness is an indicator of not normal (alternative) development of the brain. It must have correlates in EEG.

Comment: "It must have correlates in EEG" -- No. It must have some *neural* correlate. EEG can capture only a small percentage of behavioral phenomena due to its relatively course spatial frequency and inability to record activity in more medial brain regions. I'd broaden your search accordingly; perhaps that will lead to more relevant literature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Abstract**
>
> **Background**
>
> According to decades of research on affective motivation in the human
>   brain, approach motivational states are supported primarily by the
>   left hemisphere and avoidance states by the right hemisphere. The
>   underlying cause of this specialization, however, has remained
>   unknown. Here we conducted a first test of the Sword and Shield
>   Hypothesis (SSH), according to which the hemispheric laterality of
>   affective motivation depends on the laterality of motor control for
>   the dominant hand (i.e., the “sword hand," used preferentially to
>   perform approach actions) and the nondominant hand (i.e., the “shield
>   hand," used preferentially to perform avoidance actions).
>
> **Methodology/Principal Findings**
>
> To determine whether the laterality of approach motivation varies with
>   handedness, we measured alpha-band power (an inverse index of neural
>   activity) in right- and left-handers during resting-state
>   electroencephalography and analyzed hemispheric alpha-power
>   asymmetries as a function of the participants' trait approach
>   motivational tendencies. Stronger approach motivation was associated
>   with more left-hemisphere activity in right-handers, but with more
>   right-hemisphere activity in left-handers.
>
> **Conclusions**
>
> The hemispheric correlates of approach motivation reversed between
>   right- and left-handers, consistent with the way they typically use
>   their dominant and nondominant hands to perform approach and avoidance
>   actions. In both right- and left-handers, approach motivation was
>   lateralized to the same hemisphere that controls the dominant hand.
>   This covariation between neural systems for action and emotion
>   provides initial support for the SSH.

Citation: Brookshire G, Casasanto D (2012) Motivation and Motor Control: Hemispheric Specialization for Approach Motivation Reverses with Handedness. PLoS ONE 7(4): e36036. doi:10.1371/journal.pone.0036036

Answer (score 0):

[Propper RE, et al. 2012. Asymmetry in Resting Alpha Activity: Effects of Handedness](http://file.scirp.org/Html/6-2250018_23957.htm)

The authors found differences in resting state alpha power depending on degree of handedness.

> **ABSTRACT**
>
> **Study Aim**: Frontal electroencephalographic (EEG) alpha band power during rest shows increased right, and/or decreased left, hemisphere activity under conditions of state or trait withdrawal-associated affect. Non-right-handers (NRH) are more likely to have mental illnesses and dispositions that involve such withdrawal-related affect. The aim of the study was to examine whether NRH might be characterized by increased right, relative to left, hemisphere activity during rest.
>
> **Methods**: The present research investigated that hypothesis by examining resting EEG alpha power in consistently-right-handed (CRH) and NRH individuals.
>
> **Results**: In support of the hypothesis, NRH demonstrated decreased right hemisphere alpha power, and therefore increased right hemisphere activity, during rest, compared to CRH.
>
> **Conclusions**: The study demonstrates further support for an association between increased right hemisphere activity and negative affect via an association between such EEG activity and NRH.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon. Would you mind elaborating on the contents of your link?